# How do I get Facebook post like Flipboard

Tags: ios, flipboard

I'm a totally beginner for IOS.
Recently, I found that Flipboard may embedded Facebook post
but I don't know how it do that.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the facebook API for android either as a .jar file or as complete source. After that you will have to create a facebook app on facebook which will be doing the task to get you data from facebook. Once you create a facebook app you will be given some oauth information which will be a key and a link I suppose. Copy  those in your downloaded facebook API source and you are ready to go. Ask users their username and password for facebook via some textbox and send it to the facebook API code. You can also use facebook API's internal function to get user info which will be good for privacy concerns from user point of view.

After you have successfully coded everything...Voila...you'll have the news feed as data and you can show it to user the way u want.

Comment: My bad...u have mentioned iOS and I mentioned android in my answer...but the procedure is same in that case also....